# Secure access to a MySQL database (which is on a website)

Tags: mysql, delphi, remote-access

I need to access my remote MySQL database (which is on a website) with a secure way.
Are there any components or libraries for this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: And you're sure the DBMS on your server even allows remote connections? Security wise this is almost always deactivated.

Comment: SSH Tunnelling (port forwarding) is a common method to make a secure connection to a remote service without exposing the service to the whole internet.

Comment: I am not sure but i think Unidac can do that

Comment: MyDAC from devart supports secure connections with SSL, SSH, and HTTP/HTTPS tunneling using SecureBridge according to their website. UniDAC is also from devart.